# Setting up new Arch Linux on VirtualBox automatically logs in as root

Tags: arch-linux, login

I'll preface this by saying I have very little to no experience setting up linux, I only know a bit about how to use the terminal.

SPECS:

- Windows 10 Home
- Intel i7-4710 2.50 GHz
- VirtualBox 5.1.4r
- archlinux-2016.08.01

I followed a WikiHow page on how to set up Arch Linux on VirtualBox with UEFI. Everything worked very smoothly.

NOTES: I am using the grub bootloader and did indeed set a root password. I even successfully created another user.

Then I shut down the virtual machine, and when I try to start again, it seems to load the install CD again. Here's the screen after I start the virtual machine:

[image: Boot page]

Then I select the first option, and after some loading I'm greeted with this screen:

[image: No login]

There doesn't seem to be any login screen, and I have to do `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` then `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash` before I can access my files.

My question is how can I have Arch prompt me for a login every time I open it? It seems to be loading the install ISO every time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you tell virtualbox to unmount the CD?

Comment: @Dan Can you clarify how to do that? Is it done this way? http://imgur.com/a/OrCTX

Answer (score 2):

> I followed a WikiHow page on how to set up Arch Linux on VirtualBox with UEFI. Everything worked very smoothly.

Don't consult random sources on the Internet to install Arch Linux or any other distribution for that matter. Always consult the [official Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide) on how to install Arch Linux.

Anyway, you need to remove the Arch Linux ISO image from the list of storage devices that VirtualBox is using. Instead of using the ISO, it will then use your storage file (probably a `.vdi` file) to boot instead.

Note that you might be able to install Arch Linux in VirtualBox using UEFI but it doesn't really work as expected. For details, see [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_in_EFI_mode) Arch Wiki page. Basically, VirtualBox tries to boot using `/boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` or `/boot/startup.nsh` assuming that `/boot` is your ESP. Therefore, it doesn't use the `.EFI` file of the boot manager (GRUB).

You can also use VirtualBox and install Arch Linux in a `MSDOS` parition label with `MBR` instead of `GPT` with `UEFI`. If you insist on using `UEFI` try the workarounds described in the link. You might also wanna give [qemu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU), [libvirt, and virt-manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libvirt) a shot.

Comment: I started from scratch and re-setup a new VM. It seems that as long as I didn't shut down the VM, I was able to login the way I expected to. However, when I followed your advice and removed the ISO from list of storage devices in VirtualBox, and when I tried starting the VM again, this is the screen I saw: http://imgur.com/a/0ZhFF. Can you advise?

Comment: @Aleck Yes, that is expected because you installed Arch in UEFI mode, again. If you want to use your new installation, you have to follow the steps listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_in_EFI_mode).

You can avoid this hassle by simply installing Arch without checking the "UEFI" checkbox. If you'd done that, you'd be using Arch right now.